# Xml Serilization Nested Classes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am sorry , but i checked every example i could and didn't get any help.
My supposed to be xml structure is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project ModelVersion="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Models>
    <Model>
      <Id>987214</Id>
      <prop1></prop1>
      <prop2></prop2>
      <Sections>
        <Section>
          <id>3548A</id>
          <prop1>true</prop1>
          <BaseSection xsi:type="Multiple">
            <prop1>Ijk</prop1>
            <prop2>Lmn</prop2>
          </BaseSection>
        </Section>
        <Section>
          <id>3548B</id>
          <prop1>true</prop1>
          <BaseSection xsi:type="Single">
            <prop1>Xyz</prop1>
            <prop2>Abc</prop2>
          </BaseSection>
        </Section>
      </Sections>
    </Model>
  </Models>
</Project>
```

And here is my class that contain object which are other classes, for sake of simplicity i have eliminated alot of objects from classes and xml

```
[XmlRoot("Project")]
[Serializable()]
public class Project
{
    [XmlElement("Model")]
    public Model Model { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Structure")]
    public Structure Structure { get; set; }

    //...more objects
}
```

and here is my Project class

```
Project settings = null;
Stream stream = File.Open(folderPath + filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Project));
settings = (Project)xs.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Now my problem is after executing this part of code, setting does contain 'Models' but it Doesn't contain Detail of Model. Models is List of Model and both are marked as [Serilizable()], Sections is list of Section and both are marked as [Serilizable()] also..

I have spent some good time on it as i thought it will be hardly 30 minutes of work but no luck..

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML, `Models` is an array of `Model` but this is not reflected correctly in your `Project` class. You need to change

```
[XmlElement("Model")]
public Model Model { get; set; }
```

to

```
[XmlArray("Models")]
public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
```

This will tell the serializer to treat `Models` as an array, which is how it's represented in the input. This would be the same for `Sections` as well:

```
[Serializable]
public class Model
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Sections")]
    public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i feel stupid, That will Do It and it did work : ). Thanks PoweredByOrange!! I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. These tiny mistakes happen all the time.